# NSLog is not working. I want to write log to system.log file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos-mojave

In applications built after a recent Xcode update, NSLog does not write logs to the `System.log` file.

I've been analyzing it through the logs in `system.log` file.
But `NSLog` doesn't work anymore.

I want to have `NSLog` write logs to `system.log` file.

I tried using `os_log` but it doesn't write log to `system.log` file.

I also tried setting the value of `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` to `disable` in Environment Variables in the project.
But that only affected `Xcode's` output console.

How can I write logs to the `system.log` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can see my project: [IRMY_LOG](https://github.com/irons163/IRMY_LOG)

This can save log in a txt file.

The key point:
freopen([pathForLog cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);